# Scope error three.js can't access JSON mesh in animate() function

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I have an imported mesh in this threejs program

where I have THREE.PointerLockControls looking at one mesh that is attached to another.

and basically **I want it to be like this**: http://eden.rutgers.edu/~shahan1/shawncorrect/

> where it can look at the mesh that's attached to a moving mesh that is moving in animate.

**I want this to be like the above link, but instead o the sphere moving, the JSON imported mesh** http://eden.rutgers.edu/~shahan1/scopeproblem/

> It won't let me move the "mesh" man shaped one, which is imported via the JSON loader.  I have a function for it commented out in the 'animate()' method and when i try that it blacks out.

Also the code is here: `http://paste.ubuntu.com/6608179/`

Is that usually when I've done stuff like this, I've had the "init" "update" and "animate" functions in use.  And here i have just init and animate...  What do I need to do to the JSON man shaped mesh?  Make it global?  Or alter the methods to achieve the desired motion?

Comment: `PointerLockControls` expects a camera as its argument.

Comment: ah, what I've been doing is adding the camera to a mesh and then passing that mesh to PointerLockControls and it seems to have "worked"  I'll try some variations now with adding the mesh to camera and such, thanks.